# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout: Binary XML file line #125

Tags: android-layout, layout-inflater, android-textinputedittext

Binary XML file line #125 | Error inflating class

I got this error with this code:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/group_ll"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/low_importance_green"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/horizontal_gap"
                android:hint="@string/group_ticket_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/due_ll"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_ll">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/group_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:maxLength="@dimen/max_group_length"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/edit_string_size" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I have seen many fixes about MaterialComponents Theme etc. but I already had all this done right.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
It was the **maxLength attribute** which caused it.

Though this is just my fault, I wanted to answer this question online, so you can see too.

**The error message is not very exact.**

So if you have this error and all fixes online are not working or already implemented right. Try looking at the attributes and if one might be causing the error.

P.S. : Why could this be an issue???